# How to find all the equivalence classes of a given language without using the Table-Filling-Algorithm.

Tags: logic, computer-science, formal-languages

I'm trying to solve an exercise problem for my formal languages class, that's to do with the **Myhill-Nerode Theorem for regular languages**. I'm given the following information and asked to find out all of the equivalence classes of the Myhill-Nerode-Relation in relation to the language.

$$\Sigma \equiv \{0,1\}$$
$$B \equiv \left\{ w \in \Sigma^* \;|\; w \text{ doesn't end in } 01 \right\}$$

My first instinct was to use the **Table-Filling-Algorithm** to find all the equivalence classes and use that to minimize the DFA but I was hoping that there would be another method to find all the equivalence classes without creating the table, which can take some time, which is something I want to avoid in my exam.

Essentially my question is, "Is there another method to find all the equivalence classes of a given language without using the Table-Filling-Algorithm?"

Comment: Hint: write out all possible strings over $\Sigma$ of length 4. Now using the definition of the equivalence relation (https://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse322/05wi/handouts/MyhillNerode.pdf), group them into equivalence classes. What does this show?

Comment: Do you just want to compute all the sets $u^{-1}L = \{x \in \Sigma^* \mid ux \in L\}$ or do you really insist on obtaining the equivalence classes of the Nerode equivalence and in this case, for which purpose?

Answer (score 1):

The Myhill-Nerode equivalence relation is that $x \sim_R y$ iff $x$ and $y$ have no distinguishing extension; i.e., if $xz$ and $yz$ are both in $B$ or both not in $B$ for any string $z$.  A way to generate the equivalence classes is to start with $B$ and $B^c$ (which are distinguished from each other by the empty string), and then split classes on every possible distinguishing extension.  In this case, if $z$ ends in $01$, then $xz$ and $yz$ are both not in $B$, and if $z$ ends in $0$ or $11$, then $xz$ and $yz$ are both in $B$, independent of $x$ and $y$.  So the only possible distinguishing extension is the string $1$.  Adding $1$ to two strings in $B^c$ (strings that end in $01$) does not distinguish them: both wind up in $B$.  So $B^c$ is an equivalence class.  Adding $1$ to two strings in $B$ (strings that don't end in $01$) *will* distinguish them if one ends in $0$ and the other doesn't.  So $B$ splits into two equivalence classes: strings that end in $0$, and strings that don't end in $01$ or $0$ (this set includes the empty string).  You wind up with three equivalence classes.